# How to pass a file uploaded from a Sencha Touch app to php?

Tags: php, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm building an app using Sencha Touch + PHP.

In Sencha Touch I made this form:

```
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            id: 'ctTitle',
            name: 'title',
            label: 'Title'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'filefield',
            id: 'ctFile',
            name: 'filePdf',
            label: 'File'
        }   
    ]
```

In my Controller there is a function to submit file to php:

```
onBtnSaveFile: function(){

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'app-resources/scripts/saveArticle.php',

        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        },

        params: {
            title: Ext.getCmp('ctTitle').getValue(),
            filePdf: Ext.getCmp('ctFile').getValue()
        },

        callback: function(options, success, response) {
            console.log(response.responseText);
        }

    });

},
```

Now in saveArticle.php, I'm using $_FILES to see the size of the uploaded file:

```
$pdf = $_FILES['filePdf'];
```

bu this line is getting the error **Undefined index: filePdf**

I think the params in AJAX request didn't send the correct data, maybe it sends a normal string not the file.

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you tried $pdf = $_FILES['ctFile'];

Comment: No beacuse ctFile is an id of the a component not a parameter.

Comment: And if your do a var_dump($_FILES); ??

Comment: Thank you for reply, but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's not for working code purpose...it's just for testing purposes...if the $_FILES array is empty then the problem is not on php side, and maybe in the sencha app

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with Sencha, but as far as I'm concerned, I am aware that when you send a form with a POST method, you have to encode that data in a certain way in order to files be sent. Is there a way to add the following attribute to your form?:

```
enctype='multipart/form-data'
```

This way you are encoding your data in a proper way that php will understand and be able to read the files from $_FILES.

Hope this helps you with your probelm.

Comment: I think I found a way putting header in AJAX request, but I'm getting this error: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data. Do you know what is causing this error?

Comment: Could you show me the code with the way you are setting the header?

Comment: I saw your edit, I think that header is correct. I have found doing some research that the way to send forms is adding the form param to your ajax call, something like 

`headers: 'yourheader',`
`form: 'yourFormNameOrId',`

Comment: can u check this plugin
http://moduscreate.com/device-camera-access-with-sencha-touch/

Comment: taxicala I tried but still getting the same error, I'll do more research. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Dibish I'll check it out.